# About Guitar Moves with Keith Richards: "There's Two Sides to Every Story"

Tags: blues

In [this interview](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ceWWMfhAvD4) of [Keith Richards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keith_Richards) titled *Guitar Moves With Keith Richards: "There's Two Sides To Every Story" (Part 1)*, what did Keith mean when he said "igo", showing the simplest trick of Jimmy Reed at 8:33 and 8:47 mins. into the video?

Comment: Do you have a link to this interview that you could add to your question?

Comment: the video here:       https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ceWWMfhAvD4

Answer (score 5, accepted):

LOL.  OK, this is just Keith Richards having no brain cells left, and a really thick British accent.  What he's saying there is "He goes..." (meaning, "He plays it like this..."), but it comes out sounding like "eeee go...".

Comment: Still that video, man. time between 14:41-14:43, what did Keef say after the host said"he sing the same, then u drop him".

Comment: LOL.  Man, I can't decipher that one.  :o)

Comment: ha ha, never mind. Keef is not a ordinary man as to speaking